# laravel doesn't display massage while redirecting back

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

in my controller i have

```
//some actions
return redirect()->back()->with("msg", "ტური შენახულია");
```

in my blade template i have

```
    @if(isset($msg))
        <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>{{$msg}}</strong></div>
    @endif
```

but it doesnt display the massage. i also try this

```
return redirect()->back()->with(["msg", "ტური შენახულია"]);



$msg = "ტური შენახულია";
return redirect()->back()->with(compact("msg"));
```

but it doesnt display anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `with()` in conjunction with a redirect, it does not place that variable inside the view, it simply flashes that data to the session.

So to grab it from your view, you will need to use `session('msg')`.  Keep in mind that will only be available for this response so you will likely want to make sure it exists before trying to display it.

Can read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects

Comment: Beat me by 17 seconds! Heh.

Answer (score 2):

While it uses the same syntax as `view()->with()`, using `with()` on a redirect doesn't work quite the same way. Your message will be stored as [flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data) and thus is in `Session::get('msg')`, not `$msg`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

and inside your view call this:

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this approach. Yes, it works, but it's sort of abusing the error handling system. Anyone with existing error handling code in templates may wind up having to put a bunch of extra code to handle *real* errors differently.